# Laptop does not suspend/sleep

Tags: suspend, amd

I would love to switch to elementary OS/ubuntu full time but there are just a few issues holding me back right now.

1. My laptop does not go to sleep when I close the lid. The fan just keeps on spinning, and battery drains too, and when I open the lid again it seems that everything just crashes , the  backlight turns on but the screen is black.
2. Amazon prime/netflix won't load Full HD videos, they're stuck in 480p
3. the audio quality from speakers is much, much worse than when in windows. also by default only 2 speakers work but I was able to solve that with the solution provided here.

My laptop is a HP envy x360 with Ryzen 3500u and I've tried updating to the latest kernel(5.9) with UKUU.

Is there any way to solve these issues?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the power button function in the OS to sleep when pressed, does it sleep?

Trying to determine if this is an OS or laptop problem.

Comment: No it doesn't i can set it to sleep, or click on suspend from the wingpanel or just close the lid, the outcome is the same.